# facebook login button setfragment error

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to setup a login with facebook into my app. I have one main activity and a couple of fragments. Using facebook sdk 3.5.2 i did everithing by facebook officaial [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/) but when i add this line `authButton.setFragment(this);` it gives me an error that my fragment is not a fragment.

> (The method setFragment(Fragment) in the type LoginButton is not
>   applicable for the arguments (FaceobookLoginFragment))

I am adding fragments from main class to action bar like this

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

String FloginTitle = "Flogin";
ActionBar.Tab FloginTab = bar.newTab();
FloginTab.setText(FloginTitle);
FloginTab.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, FloginTitle, FaceobookLoginFragment.class));
bar.addTab(FloginTab);
```

And this is the listener

```
public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private final FragmentActivity fActivity;
private final String ftag;
private final Class fragmentClass;
private Fragment fragment;


public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class fragmentClass ) {
    this.fActivity = activity;
    this.ftag = tag;
    this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;

    this.fragment = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (fragment == null) {
        // instantiate a new fragment for the given class
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(fActivity, fragmentClass.getName());
        // place in the default root viewgroup - android.R.id.content
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, ftag);
    } else {
        if (fragment.isDetached())
            ft.attach(fragment);
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        ft.detach(fragment);
    }       
}
```

And Facebook Fragment

```
public class FaceobookLoginFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "FBLOGINFRAGMENT";

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_login_layout, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(new FaceobookLoginFragment());
    return view;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG , "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

// prints a hashkey for facebook app data
public void printHashKey() {

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.mio.discounthunter", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("TEMPTAGHASH KEY:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: found out why.. facebook sdk only works with android support library so the solution is to use import android.support.v4.app.* all over my app and re factor everything that involves support library...

Comment: Rather than writing an Update in the end of the question, post it as an answer and accept it. Because it works :)

Comment: Is this the only solution here? refactor my whole app? that's depressing. I think I'll keep looking for another solution a while longer.

Comment: OK that was a lot easier to do than I expected.

Comment: Facebook, shame on you :-/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setFragment(this)`

You can use `onActivityResult` in your `Activity` and call the fragment's `onActivityResult` from there like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    _loginFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Thanks to the original answer by @Andre Classen found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26695501/2082569