# facebook login in android LoginButton.setFragment

Tags: android, facebook

I have problem with the LogginButton:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
```

I'm using Fragment that not from the support.
`.setFragment` get only Fragment from the support.

How to fix it ? (with not to change to fragment from the support)

Answer (score 7):

So , in my case switching to the support library was no option i have solved it this way:

Don't use setFragment , instead override the onActivityResult in your Acitvity and call the fragment onActivityResult from there.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    _loginFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Had the same scenario. Worked smoothly..Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Changing your fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment is the only solution.